# LightGBM incrementally construct Dataset

Tags: lightgbm

I want to construct a LightGBM `Dataset` object from very large X and y, which can not be load to memory. Is there any method that can construct Dataset in "batch"? eg. something like

```py
import lightgbm as lgb

ds = lgb.Dataset()
for X, y in data_generator():
    ds.add_new_data(data=X, label=y)
```

Answer (score 2):

regarding the data there are a few hacks, for example, if your data has numeric, you make sure the precision are too long, e.g. probably two digits would be enough (it depends on your data). or if you have categorical data make sure you store them with digits. but probably you are looking for a better approach

There is a concept called incremental learning. Basically you make a model (a tree) in your first iteration using the first batch of data. Then for your next model, you use that tree as a template and only updates the values (you can also allow for shrinkage). you can use the `keep_training_booster` for such scenario and please read on your own to learn the mechanism.

The third technique is you make multiple models: say you divide your data into N pieces and make N models, then use an ensemble approach. This way you have used your entire data with N number of observations.