Does TensorFlow decision forest support incremental learning?
I want to predict lead time in supply chain, where dependent features are material, vendor, price, quantity,etc....., this can be done by using random forest regression model, but random forest regression model does not support incremental learning, so I am looking for other model that supports incremental learning as well as the model which supports GPU.
I have tried random forest regression model and  support vector machines, in random forest regression model incremental learning was problem and in SVM handling categorical data was problem.

You can try the LightGBM model, it is simpler that Neural models and it can handle large-scale data and supports GPU acceleration. LightGBM has capabilities for incremental learning using continued training with additional data, which can be particularly useful for dynamic supply chain data. You can look at this question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62403884/lightgbm-incrementally-construct-dataset

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
